# php add fixed date value to strtotime()

Tags: php, datetime, time, strtotime

I'm using `strtotime($my_time);` to create timestamps that I use in php math.

The variable `$my_time` is in `HH:mm:ss` 24h format pulled from the database.

I'm setting the time but I don't know what date is being produced. For this reason I'm trying to set a fixed date. I tried the followng but I'm getting wrong results in my calculations.

```
strtotime('2007-12-21', $my_time);

strtotime( '+1 day', strtotime('2007-12-21', $my_time); //should produce 2007-12-21 00:00:00 ?
```

Please help me understand how to set a fixed date in `strtotime()` and dynamic time?

note: the `DateTime` class isn't an option in the code I'm using.

Comment: I was just about to mention using `DateTime` when you updated your question!

Comment: @JohnConde haha yes, I knew people would recommend it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should concatenate the strings into one argument, not providing two arguments.

```
strtotime('1970-01-01 ' . $my_time);
```

I've also switched to 1970-01-01 as the date because that's when UNIX timestamps begins, which gives you seconds only to work with. It may be easier to troubleshoot that way because you can see at a glance if one number is bigger than another, you can also easily spot failures such as >86400 and so on.

Comment: Thanks! I had no idea that the date effects execution time. Is that what you are saying?

Comment: No, I don't think it affects execution time. I'm just saying that smaller numbers may be easier to troubleshoot because they are easier to understand for humans.

Comment: thanks! voted for working code and extra suggestion about UNIX timestamp :)

Answer (score 3):

strtotime espects as second value an integer in the Unix timestamp format, as seen on [PHP Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

Maybe you intended to use the dot, instead of the comma, like this:

```
strtotime('2007-12-21 ' . $my_time);

strtotime( '+1 day', strtotime('2007-12-21 ' . $my_time);
```

Answer (score 2):

It just might just be a space issue. Try:

```
strtotime( '+1 day', strtotime('2007-12-21 ' . $my_time);
```

FYI, if `$my_time` really does contain a value of `00:00:00` then you can safely omit it from `strtotime()`. It will work without it.

Comment: Thanks! I was just illustrating the format with `00:00:00` it holds actual time